# Non-capturing named group

Tags: php, regex

There is a way to create a named group that will handle the specific "pattern" which be used in the future of the pattern without capturing at the moment I declare it in DEFINE?

I mean something like that

```
(?(DEFINE)(?<_INT>[0-9]+))(Number\s(?P>_INT))
```

It works fine, but _INT will return as match (and NULL).

My pattern is much bigger than that and I need to find a way to make an order to make it readable.

Sorry for my English ;o

Comment: I don't think so. There's no distinction made between capturing for back-references and capturing to return to the application.